# Bootstrap confirmation modal window service

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Hi guys I have service which opens bootstrap modal window (ui-bootstrap) with question and 2 buttons. What I want is to handle if user hit ok or no button and than I would like to delete item or just close the modal window. And I would like to call this service on every place (in different controllers) where user can delete any item. Question is how to modify this service to do so?

Template :

```
> <div class="modal-header">
>     <h4>Delete confirmation</h4> </div> <div class="modal-body">
>     <p>Item will be permanently deleted! Do you want to continue?</p> </div> <div class="modal-footer">
>     <button type="button" class="btn" 
>         data-ng-click="cancel()">No</button>
>     <button class="btn btn-danger" 
>         data-ng-click="ok();">Ok</button> </div>
```

Service :

```
myApp.service('modalService', [
    '$modal', function ($modal) {
        var self = this;
        var modalInstance = null;

        self.open = function ($scope, path) {
            modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: path,
                scope: $scope
            });
        };

        self.close = function () {
            modalInstance.dismiss('close');
        };

        return self;
    }
]);
```

Calling service:

```
> $scope.deleteTest = function () {
>     modalService.open($scope,'js/app/templates/confirmation-modal.html');
// I want to continue to do my delete if Ok button on modal was hit ....
> };
```

Comment: Change your function to **return** the ModalInstance (or at least its result), instead of storing it in a service field. That way, the caller can register callbacks and do whatever they want when the modal is closed or dismissed. https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal

Comment: But what is totaly unclear to me is how to bind button in template with service. Because if I declare something in service like this $scope.ok = function () {
return modalInstance} error ocures undefined $scope. I totaly new in custom services like this one.